# sockets.h problem with cygwin and eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, sockets, cygwin, mingw

I keep getting this error:
c:\cygwin\usr\include/cygwin/socket.h:55:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '__uid32_t'

My code is mininmal and still can't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have include C:\cygwin\usr\include to compiler path and linker to C:\cygwin\usr\lib

please advise

Comment: I'm sure if it's related, but if you rely on the gcc 4.3 version, there's a bug with the network code in the compiler.

Comment: i just checked am using 4.5 from mingw...

Answer (score 3):

Headers under `C:\cygwin\usr\include`, and libraries under `C:\cygwin\usr\lib`, are for use in the Cygwin environment -- which means they should be referred to via their Cygwin paths, `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`.

I haven't used mingw, but I don't think it's part of Cygwin, and I wouldn't expect it to be able to use Cygwin's headers and libraries.

If you're going to use mingw, you should use the headers and libraries that are installed with it.  Don't specify any Cygwin-related directories.

Or you can use Cygwin's gcc (which is optional; you'll have to install it with `setup.exe`).  In that case, you can run `gcc` or `make` from the command line.  I'm not sure whether Cygwin and Eclipse play nicely together.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Eclipse has support for Cygwin and "should" automatically recognize it, although I have not gotten that working.

Answer (score 0):

I know  this question is old, and I'm using a newer version, but I had a similar issue and it was resolved by moving `#include <sys/socket.h>` one line above `#include <sys/types.h>`.

Something in `types.h` appears to be blocking `socket.h` (not sure how). Wish I had more details on the cause, but hope the solution helps some.